# Plot many rasters on the same graph, one on top of the other, using a certain angle in R

Tags: raster, r, plot

I wish to create a plot with multiple raster layers in R, but plot them in a certain angle so that all layers can be properly seen. What I have in mind is a plot like the following, taken from here: https://pubs.usgs.gov/ds/691/ds691.pdf
[image]

How can I do this in R?

Comment: Can be done in 3d using the `rgl` package, but I think you have to massage `raster` objects into surfaces for `rgl`...

Comment: Here's how to do it (using ggplot2): http://urbandemographics.blogspot.com.es/2016/04/creating-tilted-and-stacked-maps-in-r.html

Comment: (See quadmesh for easy coercion of raster to rgl's quad mesh.)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a simplistic and raw example using `quadmesh`. You have to set the 3rd coordinate to a constant - otherwise it will appear as relief - here done after using that as the data. The `material$col` is the quad-indexed values of the data, with a raw scaling of the values into a separate palette for each just to illustrate.

```
library(quadmesh)
library(rgl)

## stack up volcano
library(raster)

r <- raster(volcano)

## make the qm in three forms
qm2 <- qm3 <- qm1 <- quadmesh(r)

## update the colours based on the data, then update the vertices
scl <- function(x) (x - min(x, na.rm = TRUE))/diff(range(x, na.rm = TRUE))
qm1$material$col <- viridis::inferno(26)[scl(qm1$vb[3, qm1$ib]) * 25 + 1]
qm1$vb[3, ] <- 1


qm2$material$col <- viridis::viridis(26)[scl(qm2$vb[3, qm2$ib]) * 25 + 1]
qm2$vb[3, ] <- 2

qm3$material$col <- rev(viridis::magma(26))[scl(qm3$vb[3, qm3$ib]) * 25 + 1]
qm3$vb[3, ] <- 3

## adding to a plot is the default
shade3d(qm1)
shade3d(qm2)
shade3d(qm3)
aspect3d(1, 1, 1)
```

To put the lines on you either have to use `lines3d` and loop over every ring (easiest to use ggplot2 fortify and visit per `group`), or decompose them all to segments and plot with `segments3d`. I have helper code to do that but it's not on CRAN.

[image]